# SQL Server Remove double quotes

Tags: sql-server, xml, character-encoding

SQL Server 2008 R2

I'm creating an XML file from SQL Server and one column is causing me problems because of " inside the varchar.

The XML looks like this after export,

```
<variantValue name="marketingInfo" value="random text.&#x0D;&#x0A;&#x0D;&#x0A; random text.&#x0D;&#x0A;&#x0D;&#x0A;"random text""/>
```

which of course breaks the xml file.

It turned out i mistook the " for a ” (U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) which is why replace didnt work. It does however still export as a regular " to XML.

How do you deal with text fields when exporting from SQL to XML in order to escape any characters that can break the XML?

SQL procedure looks something like this,

```
declare @pricat xml

set @Pricat = (
    --Pricat HEAD
    select ..some attributes
        --Pricat ROWS
        ,(select ..sone attributes

            -- PriceBracket 1 (PRE)
            ,(select ..some attributes
            for xml path ('priceBracket'), type)

            -- PriceBracket 2 (Supp)
            ,(select ..some attributes
            for xml path ('priceBracket'), type)

            -- VariantValue 01
            ,(select ..some attributes
            for xml path ('variantValue'), type)

            -- VariantValue 02
            ,(select ..some attributes
            for xml path ('variantValue'), type)

        for xml path ('sprProduct'), type)
from prh
FOR XML PATH ('Pricat')
)

-- Not sure if this is a good way to add verion and encoding tag.        
--select '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>' + cast(@Pricat as varchar(max)) as xml
select @b24Pricat
```

XML file is created as below,

```
declare @filename varchar(100)
declare @cmd varchar(256)
declare @date datetime

set @date = getdate()
set @filename = cast(datepart(year,@date) as varchar)+cast(LEFT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), @date, 101), 2) as varchar)+cast(datepart(day,@date) as varchar)
set @filename = @filename + '_' + cast(datepart(minute,@date) as varchar )+ cast(datepart(second,@date) as varchar)
set @filename = 'blabla_' + @filename + '.xml'
-- -C 28591
set @cmd = 'bcp "exec db..procedure 1,2,3,4" queryout "c:\export\'+ @filename +'" -T -c -C 28591'

EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Comment: can you mention the sql for generating the xml

Comment: Its big and i need to edit it alot before i can post it. With a simple select on the text column i get same problem so i dont think the double quotes problem is related to the xml.

Comment: Sql automatically escapes characters when using xml operations like below

_DECLARE @s VARCHAR(10) = 'sdf"aa';

SELECT @s '@s'
FOR XML PATH('f')_

Comment: @fish, I suspect the code that generates the XML is also performing string concatenation.  `XQuery`, `FOR XML` and `XML` node methods in SQL Server should replace invalid characters with entity references, resulting in valid XML.  We'll need to see at least a simplified version of the generation code.

Comment: Just noticed that Management Studio prints the xml double quote as ” (U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK). If i use that in replace it works. Is there still somthing wrong in my code or is this inherit from column itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if its the whole answer but changing the BCP command as below solved my problem.

```
set @cmd = 'bcp "exec db..procedure 1,2,3,4" queryout "c:\export\'+ @filename +'" -T -w
```